# Easy Sudoku Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

This is an easy sudoku puzzle (no. 90) from my blog.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just like it says on the tin, this is an easy Sudoku puzzle. I suspect the downvotes are because such puzzles are super abundant over the internet; I liked solving this one though, and there's nothing wrong with posting the basic stuff once in a while.

Here's the completed grid:

> [image]

Everything solved without any advanced logic, so I won't be doing a full write-up. The r4c8 square (highlighted) seems to be telegraphed by the positioning of the initial clues, and indeed, it is a [naked single](http://sudopedia.enjoysudoku.com/Naked_Single.html). Apart from that, I don't think I ever checked the candidates for a square; no pencilmarking was needed whatsoever.

So, an enjoyable puzzle all in all, +1, would solve again on my next coffee break.

(As for the personal preference gallup, I like my sudoku in either "coffee break filler" or "artisanal sudoku" (à la [CTC](https://www.youtube.com/c/CrackingTheCryptic)) variety.)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I cut it out and posted it below mine on my blog. I often do that as it makes it look as if somebody is actually interested in my puzzles. I will try posting a tough puzzle next. Regarding your reference to Cracking the Cryptic, somebody once sent them one of my killer sudokus and they solved it on their YouTube channed: <https://andrewspuzzles.blogspot.com/2019/06/killer-sudoku-puzzle-no-3.html>